# How to remove Linkwithin / Related Posts?

Tags: html, widget, blogger

I wanted to try out Linkwithin, a widget to show related posts underneath each post, to see how it looks like and stuff. On the Linkwithin website you can install the widget by clicking on a link which directed you to Blogger. I added the widget to my blog.

Now I would like to get rid of it, but on the Linkwithin website it's stated NOWHERE how to remove Linkwithin! So I tried deleting the widget but it wasn't showing up. So I went to the HTML source code and wanted to delete it straight from there, but I simply can't find it...

Does anyone know how to get rid of it, or can find it in the code?

Website is [www.wldhrts.com](http://www.wldhrts.com)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove that widget from your blog. It's the first widget on your right sidebar (just above the search box).

Move to

> Blogger >> template >> edit Template >>

Search for 'id='HTML2' it's the widget holding your linkwithin code. You should be able to find code like

```
<b:widget id='HTML2' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'>...</b:widget>
```

Remove the whole widget.

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively set nRelate on your Blog which is way better then LinkWithin.Here is the link of complete post explaining every process step by step. nRelate also offer you to earn some money by showing ads on your Blog or website.
http://sarcaassm.blogspot.com/2014/02/setup-nrelate-widget-to-your-blog.html

Answer (score 0):

it is not always 'HTML2'. it depends upon where you have it. just try to reinstall it from linkwithin site, you will see codes, see what are they, note down on notepad and then search them in tempelate and remove. that will only work super fast. you may also like '[how to remove it only from blogger home](http://www.choozurmobile.com/2015/09/how-to-remove-linkwithin-related-posts.html)'